# getting index of nan values in numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Getting the index of nan values from where condition and passing it to original array         but it is returning empty

```
#Input
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data'
iris_2d = np.genfromtxt(url, delimiter = ',', dtype = 'float')# random number from 0 to 150 as high is none
iris_2d[np.random.randint(150, size = 20), np.random.randint(4, size = 20)] = np.nan


( iris_2d[np.where(iris_2d[a,b]==np.nan)])
```

Comment: By definition `nan!=nan` which is why your code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the data from the [url](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data)  that you mentioned, and saved it as 'iris_data.txt'. Try the following code. It gives you indices of `nan` in the `numpy` array `iris_2d`.

```
import numpy as np

iris_2d = np.genfromtxt('iris_data.txt', delimiter = ',', dtype = 'float')

nan_indx = np.argwhere(np.isnan(iris_2d))

print nan_indx.shape
print " " 
print nan_indx[0:5,:]
```

Output:

```
(150, 2)

[[0 4]
 [1 4]
 [2 4]
 [3 4]
 [4 4]]
```